# Python: Identify and extract datetime from a paragraph

Tags: python, datetime, extract, data-analysis

I am trying to extract date and time range from a paragraph, but I am unable to do so.

I tried to use the [datefinder](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/) library, but it didn't recognize the date.

I am not too familiar with Regex code. Can someone please help me ?

A sample of the paragraph might be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim Monday, March 24, 2021 between 10:00 AM and 11:00 AM GMT. 
Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in MIP_2IT on 2020-01-01 at 10:00 (CT)* 2020-06-09 at 15:00 (UTC/GMT)** 
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

As you can see in this sample, date and time is referenced in two places and i would need to get them in a list. Can you help me with some code ?

Comment: You appear to potentially have many different date/time formats in your text.  You should first figure out how many formats there are, and then update your question with this information.

Comment: The formats are not standardized ... That's the problem. I was wondering if there was any data analysis library that could do this.

Comment: You *could* use NLP to identify dates, time, but I think it will be reaaaally complicated for this task